# Strange error message about GCC inline assembly

Tags: c, linux

Consider:

```
int main()
{
    __asm__("movl $0x1,%%eax;
            movl $0x0,%%ebx;
            int $0x80;
            ":::"eax","ebx");
}
```

I try to simulate the behavior of exit() in Linux. But in modern Linux I find it's very difficult to do that since some exit handlers will be called after exit().

So I write an old version of exit(). Maybe 10 years ago you can find it in some code.
I compile it with GCC.

```
gcc -o exit exit.c
```

And it gives me these messages.

```
exit.c: In function ‘main’:
exit.c:3:13: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
exit.c:3:5: error: missing terminating " character
exit.c:4:13: error: expected string literal before ‘movl’
exit.c:6:27: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
exit.c:6:13: error: missing terminating " character
```

I have carefully examined my code and I don't think my code is wrong. So what is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have embedded newlines inside quoted strings

```
// bad
"two
lines"
```

Rewrite as

```
// good
"two\n"
"lines"
```

The preprocessor will join the strings seamlessly, to

```
"two\nlines"
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Maybe some of my reading materials make some mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember of inline assembly, you probably need to terminate each line with `\n\t` after the semicolon or something like that.

Clarification:
It is not enough to terminate each line in inline assembly with `;`. Inline assembly is fed directly to the assembler by gcc as a string. If you do not terminate each line with `\n`, the assembler will get strings like `movl $0x1,%%eax;movl $0x0,%%ebx;` which it will not be able to parse. You probably do not need to use `\n\t` any longer since gcc can handle assembly files where commands are not preceded by `\t`.