# "warning : missing terminating " character" in false condition

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, warnings

I'm compiling my game engine code on [Visual Studio 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2015) and [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) using GCC.

I used many compilers for my code and only GCC shows the warning:

> warning : missing terminating " character

The code is like following:

```
#if 1
   ...
#else
  asm __volatile__("
    some assembly code
    ...
  "::: );
#endif
```

I know recent GCC does not accept new lines in a string, but I don't know why the GCC preprocessor spews warning for false block.

I know my writing style of inline assembly is old, but they are in a false conditional block. I don't want to touch them because there are so many.

How can I avoid this warning in false conditional block except suppressing all the warnings?

I compiled my code with Armcc, [Microsoft Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) ([2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2005), [2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2008), [2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2012), [2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2013), and [2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2015)) and [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang). They don't show this kind of warning; only GCC does.

If the warnings are for the code in the TRUE conditional block, I will fix them. But these warnings are for FALSE conditional blocks which should not be evaluated.

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10205777/5588347) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange error message about GCC inline assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205691/strange-error-message-about-gcc-inline-assembly)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: The question is not about "missing terminating character" error per se (the OP knows perfectly well that it is missing), but rather about why it happens in a seemingly *disabled* stretch of code.

Answer (score 0):

C preprocessor is *string-literal aware*. Per language grammar, string literal is one of the preprocessing tokens

> ```
> preprocessing-token:
>   header-name
>   identifier
>   pp-number
>   character-constant
>   string-literal
>   punctuator
>   each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
> ```

This is, of course, perfectly expected, since otherwise the preprocessor wouldn't be able to tell `MACRO_NAME` from `"MACRO_NAME"` (the latter being just a string).

For this reason, your string literals are supposed to be formatted properly for preprocessing purposes. I presume that GCC sees the first `"` and begins interpreting the sequence as a string literal, but then abandons the attempt (due to missing terminating `"`) and files it under the generic "cannot be one of the above" category, accompanying it with a warning.

You seem to be assuming that conditional inclusion works at the higher preprocessing level than recognition of such tokens as string literals. This assumption is incorrect. The preprocessor has no other choice but to parse the "disabled" stretch of the code as well.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed explanation.
My question is why only gcc shows that warning while the others don't.
I have been trying to remove warnings as much as I can and I wanted to remove this waring. But if I can not, I will leave the warning as it is.

Comment: @yhorimoto: Warnings are non-normative. GCC decided that it is worthy of a warning, while Clang (for another example) doesn't.